# While trying to fill the null values in my dataframe df 's "item_weight" column accord. to "Item_Identifier " .error is coming

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-cleaning, fillna

```
avg_weight = df.pivot_table(index = "Item_Identifier",values = "Item_Weight")
df_bool =df[df["Item_Weight"].isnull()]
df.loc[df_bool,'Item_Weight'] = df.loc[df_bool,'Item_Identifier'].apply(lambda x: avg_weight[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) if I were you:

```
df["Item_Weight"] = df["Item_Weight"].fillna(df["Item_Weight"].mean())
```

Comment: that will not fill it according to  weight of item identifier as I have in pivot table in the code. This will fill it according to average weight of all the items.